# Connection problem with ajp between Apache/2.4.37 (centos 8) and tomcat 9.0.41 (503, service unavailable) AH00896 error

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp

This is the httpd.conf

```
Listen 80 
ProxyPass /ajpsubdir ajp://127.0.0.1:8009 secret="mysecret"
ProxyPassReverse /ajpsubdir ajp://127.0.0.1:8009 secret="mysecret"
```

this is the tomcat/conf/server.conf

```
 <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" secretRequired="true" secret="mysecret" />
```

On http://127.0.0.1/ajpsubdir

I get the error

503, service Service Unavailable.

mod_js seems to be started correctly in mod_jk.log

```
[Wed Jan 13 20:40:15 2021] [29351:139672606480704] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3591): mod_jk/1.2.48 initialized
```

Apache error.log

```
[proxy_ajp:error] [pid 29623:tid 140400610215680] [client 94.36.170.148:1128] AH00896: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

Any ideas ?

Thx

Comment: Just a wild guess not knowing much about tomcat (hence not a fully fledged response), but is the problem maybe the :;1 listener? Maybe tomcat is using an IPv6-only listener, and Apache is trying an IPv4 connection. Please ignore my comment if that is not applicable, was just a very uneducated guess

Comment: solved removing address="::1" in the connector configuration.

Comment: you can write an actual answer to yourself if you want, and accept it. Could be useful to make it easier to find for somebody else getting to this question here via Google & co!

Comment: @AlexBtz care to elaborate on what you meant by removing the address="::1" ? Do you mean remove the attribute entirely like so :
`<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" port="8009" redirectPort="8443" secretRequired="true" secret="mysecret" />`